# How to add a condition to count function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these tables Course, subscription,subscription_Course(A table that creates a relation between Course and subscription), and another with Student. I want to Select all the id_courses that have a subscription count higher than 1 but only want to count the subscriptions from different students. Example: If a Student Subscribes two times the same course I want to have a condition that enables the count function to not count more than one time in these cases

These are my tables:

Student:

| idStudent(pk) | cc | nif |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30348507 | 232928185 |
| 2 | 30338507 | 231428185 |
| 3 | 30438507 | 233528185 |
| 4 | 30323231 | 3232132 |

Subscription

| idsubscription(pk) | Student(fk) | value_subscription | vouchercurso | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | null | 2021-11-01 |
| 2 | 2 | 150 | null | 2021-12-11 |
| 3 | 3 | 160 | null | 2021-01-03 |
| 4 | 4 | 500 | null | 1996-11-07 |
| 5 | 1 | 900 | null | 2001-07-05 |
| 6 | 2 | 432 | null | 2021-05-09 |

Subscription_Course

| idsubscription(PK/fk) | id_Course(pk/fk) | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 9 |
| 2 | 4 | 15 |
| 3 | 5 | 12 |
| 6 | 3 | 9 |
| 5 | 4 | 16 |
| 2 | 6 | 20 |
| 6 | 5 | 4 |

For example, when counting within my table Subscription_Course only the id_course:5 would have a count higher than 1 because 3 and 4 have a subscription from the same student.

I have this query for now:

```
Select id_Course 
From Subscription_Course 
Group by id_Course 
Having Count (id_Course)>1
```

I don't know what to do to add this condition to the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you need to join to Subscription  and count unique Student id's:

```
select id_Course 
from Subscription_Course sc
join Subscription s
  on s.idsubscription = sc.idsubscription
group by id_Course 
having Count(distinct Studentid)>1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the `Subscription_Course` table with the `Subscription` table in order to access the `id_Student` column. Then just count the distinct `id_Student` values for each `id_Course` value.

```
SELECT
    Subscription_Course.id_Course,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Subscription.id_Student) AS student_count
FROM Subscription_Course
INNER JOIN Subscription
ON Subscription_Course.id_Subscription = Subscription.id_Subscription
GROUP BY Subscription_Course.id_Course
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Subscription.id_Student) > 1
ORDER BY student_count DESC;
```

With result:

```
 id_course | student_count 
-----------+---------------
         3 |             2
         4 |             2
         5 |             2
```